# EF 6 System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-6

I recently upgraded from Entities Framework 5 to Entities Framework 6 Alpha 2 and I am getting the following error:

> Method not found: 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()'.

This is getting hit when I call

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password)) {}
```

This used to work fine before not sure why it's springing this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest a better title. Every single question about this release of EF _could_ use the same title you did.

Comment: There's a Microsoft Connect bug filled regarding this issue: 
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/801350/microsoft-aspnet-providers-core-incompatible-with-ef6

Comment: @Pawel: that's is not correct. MVC doesn't cares about EF.

Comment: @Ours - I actually think that there are parts that do care about EF like the one mentioned in the link above.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

EF 6 does not have `System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext`. EF 6 has moved some types, including `ObjectContext`, from `System.Data.Entity.dll` into `EntityFramework.dll`, and changed their namespaces. The fact that you get this error suggests you haven't attempted to recompile your application, you've simply replaced `EntityFramework.dll` and hoped for the best. That won't work. You need to update your code to work with EF 6: you need to remove your references to `System.Data.Entity.dll`, and update your code to refer to the new types.

It just might be possible for the reference to the `IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext` property to be in some library you're using, but most likely it'll be in your own code. The error message (in the part you didn't include in your question) should tell you where it is coming from.

Comment: I have removed all references to System.Data.Entity.dll, I have recompiled and get no errors. The only thing I see referencing IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext is in my DB.context.TT file.  What else will I need to do?

Comment: I was using EF 5 DBContext Generator before what can I use for EF6?

Comment: @The EF 5 DBContext generator still works as long as you don't use SQL Server stored procedures or user-defined functions. The references in the `.Context.tt` are only used if you do use them, but if you did, you should have seen them in the generated files (`.Context.cs`) too. Again, the error message should give you more details, but since those details aren't in the question, I can't make a reasonable guess.

Comment: {"Method not found: 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()'."}

Comment: The source is coming from System.Web.Providers

Comment: Unfortunately there is not much other details on the error but I see there is a User class that inherits System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase

Comment: "The source is coming from System.Web.Providers" -- *that* could be a very relevant bit. If you're getting that from [Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core) (indirectly), which depends on EF5+, and that uses methods in EF5 that no longer exist in the same form in EF6, you cannot use it with EF6 unless you can find or create a different version that does not use those EF5 methods.

Comment: Ah gotcha so System.Web.Profile is the culprit that doesn't work well with EF6?

Comment: I'm in the same boat. This is a great show stopper. I can't move forward because I'm using Stored Procedures. Will have to wait to try the new bits in EF 6 namely Async. :(

Comment: @LenielMacaferi For that, are you able to modify the `.tt` template file to make the generated C# code refer to the new `IObjectContextAdapter`'s namespace?

Comment: @hvd I modified the `.tt` template to make use of theses namespaces: `using System;
using System.Data.Entity; 
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;` Didn't try adding the new `IObjectContextAdapter`'s namespace... but the error I'm getting comes from the `Membership` class from ASP.NET. This places me in that condition you mention above where you say that it comes from `AspNet.Providers`...

Comment: @LenielMacaferi Ah, sorry, I assumed based on the "I'm using Stored Procedures" that you were having a similar but not exactly identical problem: the default `.tt` file also causes problems when stored procedures are used (see the third comment here), but they're fixable from your end. Sorry, yes, you're stuck, then.

Comment: Why did they move it?

Comment: @TimLovell-Smith So that there is no dependency on the system `System.Data.Entity.dll`. This is necessary in order to, for example, get `enum` support working with .NET 4.0, for which the system DLL simply lacks support.

Comment: @hvd I don't see how that helps remove the dependency. Don't you remove the dependency by simply not referencing that assembly?

Comment: @TimLovell-Smith Sorry, that was unclear. They moved it to a different assembly so that they can use it without referencing `System.Data.Entity.dll`. I think they moved it to another namespace because moving it to a different assembly *without* moving it to another namespace causes problems if both assemblies are loaded.

Comment: Funny because I created a brand new application and added EntityFramework as a nugetpackage and ended up with this issue...Certainly not because I just willy nilly replaced a dll.

Comment: @kelton52 In this answer, I stated that it was most likely coming from the OP's own code, based on the information available in the question. With the limited information about your case, that would not be my first guess. If you created a brand new application, then I don't see how the reference can be coming from your own code. Did you perhaps add any other NuGet packages? If so, is it possible that any of them only work with EF5? At any rate, as I put in this answer, the error message should tell you where it's coming from.

Answer (score 24):

For me updating these below worked:
`using System.Data.Objects; --> using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;`

`using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses; --> using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses;`

Answer (score 14):

I'm also using `EF 6`.

I managed to solve the problem uninstalling the package [`Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core`](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core) v. 1.2. I'm using version 1.1 instead. If you're like me and is using `LocaDb`, you'll have to uninstall the `LocaDb` package because it depends on that package. Of course you'll have to reinstall LocaDb again...

You can grab v. 1.1 using the NuGet Package Manager Console inside Visual Studio:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core -Version 1.1
```

---

There's a Microsoft Connect bug filled regarding this issue:

[Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core incompatible with EF6](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/801350/microsoft-aspnet-providers-core-incompatible-with-ef6)

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I am getting the same error as the thread author except the stack trace shows it coming from System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.EnsureDatabaseCreated, which is getting called by System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser.

Comment: @Roger: I did not delete your answer. I have enough reputation to see your deleted answer. I just copied and pasted the link in my answer because I thought that could be helpful. I think your answer was deleted by the community because it had 1 link only and when an answer gets down voted it goes to a pool (Reviews section here at SO) for others to review and decide if it should be closed. Hope it helps you understand what happened.

Comment: OK. So I guess it's frowned upon to post a link like I did, even when relevant? I don't really understand that.

Comment: @Roger: when you want to share a link like that it's recommended that you put a comment under the question or an existing answer. See here for more info about deleted answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers "barely more than a link to an external site"

Comment: The Microsoft Connect link is now dead.

Answer (score 5):

The new 2.0 version of the providers (http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core/) are EF6 compatible (they'll actually only work with EF6).

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve this by removing the AspNet Providers I had installed through Nuget, which was marked as deprecated. Doing this also uninstalled Entity Framework.

I then installed the new AspNet Universal Providers, followed by Entity Framework 6, and all my problems were fixed.

Comment: The new Providers? You mean 1 year old version 1.2? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I may be a bit behind the times :)

Comment: Well, then, I'll report that 1.2 doesn't work. 1.1. Seems to work for now.

Answer (score 1):

Check This Link

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/03/01/whats-new-in-entity-framework-6.aspx

I Updated the EF 6.2 and get same error and find the solution as fallows

Change the namespace System.Data.Entity to System.Data.Entity.Core, including any references to System.Data.* namespaces (for example, System.Data.Objects becomes System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects).

Answer (score 1):

That happens when entity framework is unable to find the method in the dotnet framework library installed in the machine. So install dotnet framework 4.5.2 or higher. It will fix the issue.

Comment: This is a good idea in general if that is the targeted framework, but it does not directly address the issue. For me, I simply modified the Context.tt template file to exclude the older assemblies and include     using System.Data.Objects. I am not sure that this would resolve the issues for anyone else here. Now if you uninstall the NuGet packages, upgrade framework, then install the new NuGet packages, I can see that working.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was the following:

1. Install the dll 'Microsoft.AspNet.DataSource' with:

   PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource
2. Reference 'Microsoft.AspNet.DataSource.dll' in your project.
3. Added the following using declarations:

   using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;

   using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;

   using Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource;
4. Removed the following using declarations:

   using System.Data.Entity;

   using System.Data.Metadata.Edm;

   using System.Data.Objects;

   using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

Voila, code is compiling and working.

Answer (score 1):

It has an old version associated with edmx file for this:

- Reinstall EF with Nuget
- Delete the .edmx file and recreate it with tables

Comment: for me I had EF6 via Nuget . I installed 5.00 to the web project and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and simple fix for me was to remove the offending assemblies (deprecated) and added a reference to the new library. The code was modified within the Context.tt and looks like this:

```
if (container.FunctionImports.Any())
{
#>
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects; // The assembly you need
using System.Linq;
<#
}
```

Before any modifications it had appeared as such:

```
if (container.FunctionImports.Any())
{
#>
using System.Data.Objects; // Error on compile
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses; // Error on compile
using System.Linq;
<#
```