# ASP.NET MVC stopped working after updating application - got problems with MembershipUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Today I updated my application to the latest versions. Now at this code:

```
Membership.GetUser();
```

I get following error:

> Method not found: 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()'.

I know that the update has changed my web.config - maybe it's because something is wrong in this file now?

Comment: You updated your application to the latest version of **what**?  Also, it looks like this question is very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106286/ef-6-system-data-objects-objectcontext-error

Comment: Of everything. :) I started my ASP.NET MVC application like 4 months ago, and now i updated everything - i had 2 pages of updates.

Comment: Look at the question I linked to in my comment.  That might take care of your problem.

Comment: Well yeah, i have read that, tried to recompile my application - sure, the error moved from `Membership.GetUser();` to `Membership.ValidateUser();`, so it's basically the same problem now. But i have no idea how to get rid of that. Joe from his thread said, that he removed all the references, but what references exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is caused by the package [`Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core`](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core) v. 1.2. I uninstalled it and then installed version 1.1. If you are also using `LocaDb`, you have to uninstall `LocaDb` package since it depends on `Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core`. You'll have to reinstall `LocaDb` afterwards.

Grab v. 1.1 using the NuGet Package Manager Console within Visual Studio:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core -Version 1.1
```

Comment: How did you uninstall Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core v. 1.2?

Comment: @IrishChieftain: I uninstalled it using Package Manager ( not the Console one ). To access it, right click your project in Solution Explorer. Search for NuGet Package Manager. If you use LocalDb, you'll have to uninstall it first. Then uninstall Providers Core v. 1.2. Now go to the console and install v. 1.1. Remember to reinstall LocalDb afterwards.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this fix. I had the same problem and did not know how to solve it!

Comment: Now 2.0.0 package is available and it fixed this problem. So uninstall Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDB, Microsoft.AspNet.Providers, and Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core then Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core -Version 2.0.0;Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDB