# Breezejs and Entity Framework 6 beta1

Tags: .net, entity-framework, breeze

Did anyone get breezejs to work with EF6 beta1?

Does anyone know if it does work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17266626/516389

it also works with the beta version of EF6