# WCF Data Services Entity Framework

Tags: web-services, entity-framework-6, nuget, wcf-data-services

I came across this question in Stackoverflow (because I am getting the same exception)

[Upgraded to EF 6 (RTM) - Getting System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext cannot be used for return type System.Data.Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499967/upgraded-to-ef-6-rtm-getting-system-data-entity-core-objects-objectcontext-c)

How can I use the [WCF Data Services Entity Framework Provider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider/)? I cannot find that Nuget package. Was it removed? Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dumb question sorry this is the reason:

[image]