# Error creating MVC 4 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, code-first

I'm getting an error "Unable to retrieve Metadata for "TeamAssignment.Models.Test.  Unable to cast object of type "System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext" to type "System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext."

This is happening whenever I try to create a controller with action/views with the code first entity framework.  I'm trying it with a simple test class that's not related to my project and even that is not getting through.

```
    namespace TeamAssignment.Models
    {
        public class Test
        {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string test { get; set; }
        }
        public class testDBContext : DbContext 
        {
        public DbSet<Test> testing { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Am I being retarded here or is something wrong with my overall program?  I was having some issues with TFS earlier and I'm trying to determine if its related to that.

Comment: What is your db provider?

Comment: I guess you are using EF6. EF 6 has moved some types, including ObjectContext, from System.Data.Entity.dll into EntityFramework.dll, and changed their namespaces. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14114136/690329) post.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you recently upgraded to EF6.

Unfortunately the MVC 4 scaffolding tools are not compatible with EF6 and there's nothing you can do except upgrade to MVC5 (if possible).

Comment: Haha thank god I asked before I spent another 2 hours beating my head on my desk.  I'll find another way to finish this.