# EF6 Type of context 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext' is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, objectcontext

I have a new project created using Visual Studio 2013 with an ADO.NET Entity Data Model (EF6).

Now I have to use some Dynamic Data function (like access to MetaTable object), so I add this code:

```
MetaModel model = new MetaModel();
        model.RegisterContext(() =>
        {
            return ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)new KiwiJuiceEntities()).ObjectContext;
        }, new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = true });
```

but I've got this error:

```
Type of context 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext' is not supported
```

Note that the project have the reference updated to EF6 (system.data.entity.core)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A new preview of Dynamic Data Provider and EntityDataSource control for EF6 has been released. Please check this out, it worked for me.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/01/30/announcing-preview-of-dynamic-data-provider-and-entitydatasource-control-for-entity-framework-6.aspx#

To register the provider:

```
MetaModel model = new MetaModel();
model.RegisterContext(
    new Microsoft.AspNet.DynamicData.ModelProviders.EFDataModelProvider(
       () => new KiwiJuiceEntities()
    ),
    new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = true }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

DynamicData do no support EntityFramework 6 yet so downgrading to EF 5 'solve' the problem.

Comment: How did you specifically "downgrade to EF5" ?

Comment: Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force, Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0 see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206090/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-package-via-nuget

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

> EF 6 does not have `System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext`. EF 6 has moved
>   some types, including `ObjectContext`, from `System.Data.Entity.dll`
>   into `EntityFramework.dll`, and changed their namespaces. The fact
>   that you get this error suggests you haven't attempted to recompile
>   your application, you've simply replaced `EntityFramework.dll` and
>   hoped for the best. That won't work. You need to update your code to
>   work with EF 6: you need to remove your references to
>   `System.Data.Entity.dll`, and update your code to refer to the new
>   types.
>
> It just might be possible for the reference to the
>   `IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext` property to be in some library
>   you're using, but most likely it'll be in your own code. The error
>   message (in the part you didn't include in your question) should tell
>   you where it is coming from.

References:

- [EF 6 System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106286/ef-6-system-data-objects-objectcontext-error/14114136#14114136)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469466
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2816241

Comment: I don't have the old reference, note the error report the correct namespace: System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext...

Comment: Yes, I see! I just overlooked! Apologies!