# Visual studio 2012 changes namespace to Entity Framework 6 context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, namespaces

I have the following namespaces in database context generated by EF6:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses;
```

When I do update the namespaces are changed to;

```
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
```

How can I avoid such situation?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "update" in this context?

Comment: You probably have a remnant of the prior version laying around. Try some of these suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106286/ef-6-system-data-objects-objectcontext-error